# CSS display change AND redirect in a text input field

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I am working on a form which should redirect the user to a different page based on what they input in the text field but I also want to display hidden div styles if they input something else. Both of these actions would only be triggered once they press continue. Can this be done? Below is the desired flow and method to recreate

[image]

Comment: Of course it can be done. There are many questions on Stack Overflow about how to do all of these things. Where are you having problems?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have the redirecting on the form sorted out, but mainly having issues with changing/displaying divs and to incorporate that into the logic. Example - If user inputs X they get redirected to new page but if they input Y then they stay on the page and get a new div displayed on that page

Comment: Then [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing what you are having troubles with. See [ask], the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: @HereticMonkey have now updated the question a little bit. Does this make a bit more sense?